# Visual Studio/C++: Find all variable accesses in code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables

It's possible to find all functions call in Visual Studio. But is there a way to do the same with variables?

Comment: Quick & dirty: comment its declaration and then compile... you should see them among the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Find all references` function. In the results you'll see the line, so you can quickly see if it is an access of the variable.

More information: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSFindAllReferences.aspx

Another dirty way is temporary commenting the declaration of the variable. Intellisense will update immediately and show errors where the variable is used.

Comment: didn't see the find reference yet, oops... that is working, but it is giving so many results with a question mark that it's useless in my case... commenting the variable out is my current solution for it, that's the only thing that actually works

Comment: You could also use `Ctrl-Shift-F` to use regular expressions and search on `variable\s+=` for assignments for example.

Comment: the idea is good... but today, I would have need it for a variable named "index"... so I would have to search for ".*(->|\.)index\s+=" and that would give too many results... Every class with a field named index would fullfill this criteria... I would have really need to make sure, that the class before the field is of a special type... something like "(.)*(->|\.)index\s+=" and "$1 instanceOf WantedClass"... but it seems, like this is not possible... although your tipps were quite good, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on a variable, you can do `Find References`. There is also `Edit` > `Find and Replace` > `Find Symbol`.